# Handle multiple dynamic resource de-allocation in case C++ constructor fails

Tags: c++, constructor

If I have multiple dynamic resource allocated in constructor with different pointers (not in a same array), what would be the decent way to cleanup in case any of them fail in constructor without using smart pointer ?

I am using below code to handle two resources case but it's not scalable if more resources are needed later.

Any idea is well appreciated.

For example,

```
class Foo {
  private:
     int *p;
     bool is_p_alloc;
     int *q;
     bool is_q_alloc;

   public:
        Foo() 
        try 
          :p(NULL), q(NULL), is_p_alloc(false), is_q_alloc(false)
        { 
           p = new int;
           is_p_alloc = true;
           q = new int;
           is_q_alloc = true;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
           if(is_p_alloc)
           {
              delete p;
              p = NULL;
           }

           if(is_q_alloc)
           {
              delete q;
              q = NULL;
           }

           throw bad_alloc();
        }

};
```

Comment: Stop using raw pointers, raw `new`s and raw `delete`s.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a smart pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single responsibility and purpose-built classes:

```
#include <memory>

class Foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
    std::unique_ptr<int> q;

public:
    Foo() : p(std::make_unique<int>()), q(std::make_unique<int>()) {}

    Foo(Foo &&) = default;
    Foo & operator=(Foo &&) = default;
};
```

Remember: Whenever you find yourself writing `new`, `delete` or a destructor, you haven't factored your library properly.

Answer (score 1):

It is all about exception handling, stack unwinding and locally reserved resources.
I have made some changes on your code, and add some comment to represent the issue and the solution.

```
class Foo {
private:
    int *p;
    bool is_p_alloc;
    int *q;
    bool is_q_alloc;
public:
    Foo() : p(NULL), q(NULL), is_p_alloc(false), is_q_alloc(false)
    {
        try{
            p = new int; // The operator new may throw an exception. If it throws an exception, then following 
                         // expressions it this block won't be executed, so you don't have to worry about them.
            is_p_alloc = true;
            q = new int; // The operator new may throw an exception, but if the previous new operator had already
                         //thrown an exception, then it was not executed anyway.
            is_q_alloc = true;
        }
        catch(...) // Good technique!
        {
            if(is_p_alloc)
            {
                delete p; // Yes, you should delete p, because if new operator in the statement "q = new int;"
                              // throw an exception, then the actual object of Foo is not totally constructed, thus
                              // the destructor of this new object of Foo can not be executed, thus the memory which
                              // is pointed by p won't be deleted from heap.
                p = NULL;
            }
            if(is_q_alloc) // If one of the new operators in the try-block throws an exception, then the the
                               // statement "is_q_alloc = TRUE;" is not executed, so the value of is_q_alloc is false.
                               // is_q_alloc will never be true in this context, and you don't have to delete the
                               // memory pointed by q because if this memory reserved in the heap, then the object of Foo is totally constructed.
            {
                delete q;
                q = NULL;
            }
            throw; // Good technique!
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the null-ness of the pointers as a way to track whether allocation has happened? `Foo() : p(), q(), r() { try { p = new int; q = new int; r = new int; } catch (...) { delete r; delete q; delete p; throw; } }`

Comment: Because I didn't take care of performance. If it was my own code, then I would write it in your way. Moreover I would use smart pointers as someone said above. :) Thanks!